# Javax XSLT transformer setParameter() not working for custom types

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I have a very simple XSLT transformer in Java:

```
this.transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(xsltTransformerSource);
this.transformer.setParameter("testobject", new MyClass());
```

Here's my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:myclass="com.mycompany.MyClass">

    <xsl:param name="testobject" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="myclass:myMethod($testobject)"/></p>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transform fails with the error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot find external method 'com.myCompany.MyClass.myMethod' (must be public).
```

But, when I instantiate a MyClass within the XSLT it works!

ie.

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="myclass:myMethod(myclass:new())"/></p>
```

I can pass string parameters without any problems as well. Is there anything wrong with what I am doing? Any idea how to get it working?

I am using Xalan for transforming the xslt

Comment: If you are using Xalan, why have you tagged the question "Saxon"? The answer is going to be different for the two products, because calls from XSLT to Java aren't standardised across products.

Comment: Removed Saxon tag. Sorry!